# Unable to remove the random numbers after the output

Tags: c++

I want to build a program that support multi-language but if I included the language selection code into the main function it will be messy, so I make another function called **language** then I wrote the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int language() {
std::cout << "1.English\n2.中文";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << language();
}
```

Then my Code::Blocks IDE gave me a warning:

```
*warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|*
```

I still can compile the code using MinGW via command prompt, but the compiled program gave me the output below:

```
1.English
2.中文4683872
```

Then I add **return 0;** after the **std::cout << "1.English\n2.中文";** but it display 0 instead of 4683872 above.

I am still learning C++ and I have no idea what happened to my code, and is there is any ways to remove those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::cout << language();` is printing an integer for you since `language()` returns an `int`. If you don't want anything to print after your text, then remove the `std::cout <<` in your `main`.

Comment: Thanks! It really does work for me, but seems that I had a time limit before accept another answer. I'll accept your answer later.

Comment: What's the real issue? He asked a question ("is there any ways[sic] to remove...?"); I answered it. I even, briefly, explained why he saw what he saw.

Answer (score 3):

In your program, you print your string first and after you print the return value of the function... That's why you have a number after the string.

Just try :

```
// I don't think your language function need to return something
// So make it void
void language() {
    std::cout << "1.English\n2.中文";
}

int main() {
    language(); // Here no need to print the value returned by the language function
    return 0;   // Main return an int, 0 is for success
}
```

---

Just to explain a bit more :

The fact that your `language()` function return an `int` value and that you are not returning anything leads to **Undefined behaviour**. That's why you get a value like `4683872`. And it is also why you have a warning at the compilation.

Comment: I have another question. If a user typed random characters instead of specified character, how to return to specified section instead of ending the program?

Comment: @ngbeslhang: Post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code: The first is that you declare `language` as returning an `int` but then not actually returning anything. This is what the warning is about. The other problem is based on the first one, and that you actually use this "returned value" even though there is none, which leads to undefined behavior.

You can solve it in two ways: Either return a valid value from the function, or declare it as returning `void` and don't use the function in an expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to select a language then your code needs to be more like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int language() {
    int choice;

    std::cout << "1.English\n2.中文";  // print menu of language choices
    std::cin >> choice;               // get selection from user
    // NB: real code would have error checking here to make sure that `choice` is valid
    return choice;                    // return selection
}

int main() {
    std::cout << language();
}
```

Comment: I felt that error checking was probably not appropriate at this stage, as the OP is evidently in the very early part of the C++ learning curve.

Comment: That is precisely the time to teach that error checking should be included _from the ground up_. Else you risk creating just another dangerously inept programmer.

Comment: Fair point, but for someone who is only just getting the hang of cin and cout, and may not even have got to conditionals etc yet, then it would probably be too much too soon. I'll add a comment though.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to get your return values sorted out!  You want the `language` function to return an output stream, since you're feeding it's output into `std::out` in `main`.  You might as well pass in an output stream into `language` so you could reuse it with a different output stream to `std::out`.  Also, `main` has to return an `int`.  Standard practice is to return `0` unless there's an error.

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& language(std::ostream& os) {
    os << "1.English\n2.中文"; 
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << language(std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to go down this route (and why would you, really?) at least follow the convention of I/O manipulators, which do not take the stream as input at the call site (which is lexically redundant).

Comment: Yes, it's much better if `language` took no args and just returned a `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

    void language() {
    std::cout << "1.English\n2.中文";
    }

    int main() {
        language();
        return 0;
    }
```